# How to prevent laptop from not restarting properly on resume from suspend?

Tags: suspend, laptop, thinkpad

I am using a ThinkPad X230 with an integrated Intel graphics card which should usually be well-supported by Linux and elementary OS. Nevertheless, I am running into the issue that occasionally the ThinkPad is not properly resuming from suspend. It then shows the following characteristics:

- the display remains black
- the light of the power button keeps blinking

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution or workaround to prevent the laptop from not properly resuming?